# Unable to find column position by name: column1 [The column name column1 was not found in this ResultSet

Tags: java, sql, spring-boot, spring-data-jpa

I have this Entity:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = "_8", schema = "acc")
@AllArgsConstructor
@NoArgsConstructor
@Getter
@Setter
public class compras {
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY)
@Id
@Column(name = "id")
private long id;
@Basic
@Column(name = "entity_id")
private Integer entityId;
@Basic
@Column(name = "subdiario")
private Integer subdiario;
@Basic
@Column(name = "periodo_tributario")
private Integer periodoTributario;
@Basic
@Column(name = "tipo_operacion")
private Integer tipoOperacion;
@Basic
@Column(name = "tipo_comprobante")
private Integer tipoComprobante;
@Basic
@Column(name = "fecha_emision")
private Date fechaEmision;
@Basic
@Column(name = "fecha_vencimiento")
private Date fechaVencimiento;
@Basic
@Column(name = "numero_serie")
private String numeroSerie;
@Basic
@Column(name = "numero_correlativo")
private String numeroCorrelativo;
@Basic
@Column(name = "importe_final")
private Integer importeFinal;
@Basic
@Column(name = "tipo_documento")
private String tipoDocumento;
@Basic
@Column(name = "numero_documento")
private String numeroDocumento;
@Basic
@Column(name = "clasificacion_bienes_servicios")
private Integer clasificacionBienesServicios;
@Basic
@Column(name = "destino")
private Integer destino;
@Basic
@Column(name = "valor")
private BigDecimal valor;
@Basic
@Column(name = "icbp")
private BigDecimal icbp;
@Basic
@Column(name = "isc")
private BigDecimal isc;
@Basic
@Column(name = "otros_cargos")
private BigDecimal otrosCargos;
@Basic
@Column(name = "tipo_moneda")
private String tipoMoneda;
@Basic
@Column(name = "tasa_detraccion")
private Integer tasaDetraccion;
@Basic
@Column(name = "tasa_percepcion")
private Integer tasaPercepcion;
@Basic
@Column(name = "medio_pago")
private Integer medioPago;
@Basic
@Column(name = "tipo_comprobante_modificado")
private Integer tipoComprobanteModificado;
@Basic
@Column(name = "numero_serie_modificado")
private String numeroSerieModificado;
@Basic
@Column(name = "numero_correlativo_modificado")
private Integer numeroCorrelativoModificado;
@Basic
@Column(name = "glosa")
private String glosa;
@Basic
@Column(name = "cui")
private String cui;
@Basic
@Column(name = "observaciones")
private String observaciones;}
```

And this Repository with a Native Query (
I need this as native since it is an example to be able to map a more complex):

```
public interface ComprasRepo extends JpaRepository <compras,Long> {
    List<compras> findAllByEntityId(int entityId);
    @Query(value = "SELECT id,fecha_emision AS FechaEmision, numero_serie AS NumeroSerie, numero_correlativo AS NumeroCorreltivo, valor AS Valor, igv AS IGV, icbp AS ICBP, isc AS ISC, otros_cargos AS OtrosCargos FROM acc._8 WHERE entity_id = :entity AND periodo_tributario = :periodo", nativeQuery = true)
    List<compras> TablaPersonal(@Param("entity") Long entityId, @Param("periodo") Integer periodo);
}
```

And when a try testing with:

```
@SpringBootTest
class DataWarehouseApplicationTests {
    @Autowired
    private ComprasRepo comprasRepo;
    @Test
    void contextLoads() {

        List<compras> resultado=comprasRepo.TablaPersonal(1L, 202201);
        for (compras record : resultado){
            System.out.println(record);
        };
    }
}
```

This return this error:

> org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException:
> Unable to find column position by name: clasificacion_bienes_servicios
> [The column name clasificacion_bienes_servicios was not found in this
> ResultSet.] [n/a]; SQL [n/a]

The problem is, column A I don't want to retrieve, I don't know why the error says not found if it's not in the query either.

Please help.

PD: The mapping of the entity is correct, it has already been tested with the FindAll method

Comment: Your query doesn't select all the columns of the table, so when JPA tries to create a `compras` instance, it can't find the columns it needs. (by the way, please use Java naming conventions)

Comment: @tgdavies can u explain me more pls

Comment: When you create a `compras` instance, you need to give it a value for the `clasificacion_bienes_servicios` field. Your `@Query` ignores that column, so there is no value for that field.

Comment: And why is your title different to you question?

Answer (score 0):

It looks like you want to read only selected fields from the table. In this case you can't use the entity class in the result list. As explained in the comment by `@tgdavis`.

**Solution**

Define a new class (POJO) containing only the fields you have in the select statement. Something like this:

```
public class TablaPersonal {
    private long id;
    private Date fechaEmision;
    private String numeroSerie;
    // ...
}
```

Then use it in the repo like this:

```
List<TablaPersonal> getTablaPersonal(...)
```