# The column name column_name was not found in this ResultSet. (Java Spring Boot)

Tags: java, spring, postgresql, spring-boot, entity

I have an entity class:

```
  @Id
    @GeneratedValue(
            strategy = GenerationType.IDENTITY
    )
    @Column(name = "l_p")
    private Long l_p;
    private String marvel_comic_character_name;
    private String comic_appearance_1;
    private String comic_appearance_2;
    private String comic_appearance_3;
    private String comic_appearance_4;
    private String comic_appearance_5;
    private String comic_appearance_6;
    private String comic_appearance_7;
    private String comic_appearance_8;
    private String comic_appearance_9;
    private String comic_appearance_10;
    private String comic_appearance_11;
    private String comic_appearance_12;
    private String comic_appearance_13;
    private String comic_appearance_14;
    private String comic_appearance_15;
    private String comic_appearance_16;
    private String comic_appearance_17;
    private String comic_appearance_18;
    private String comic_appearance_19;
    private String comic_appearance_20;
    private String comic_appearance_21;
    private String comic_appearance_22;
    private String comic_appearance_23;
    private String comic_appearance_24;
    private String comic_appearance_25;
    private String comic_appearance_26;
    private String comic_appearance_27;
    private String comic_appearance_28;
    private String comic_appearance_29;
    private String comic_appearance_30;
    private String comic_appearance_31;
    private String comic_appearance_32;
    private String comic_appearance_33;
    private String comic_appearance_34;
    private String comic_appearance_35;
```

And repository :

```
 @Query(
      value="SELECT COUNT(marvel_comic_character_name) " +
      "FROM marvel_super_heroes WHERE marvel_comic_character_name ~* ':character'",
      nativeQuery = true)
    List<Character> countAllCharacterOccurences(@Param(value = "character")String character);`
```

And when I try to test the result, I receive

> Unable to find column position by name: l_p [The column name l_p was not found in this ResultSet.] [n/a]; SQL [n/a]

for database I use PostgreSQL

I've tried this solution but not worked:
[Unable to find column position by name: column1 [The column name column1 was not found in this ResultSet](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/76692158/unable-to-find-column-position-by-name-column1-the-column-name-column1-was-not)

Comment: If your goal is to get the count() into the field `l_p`, then modify your query to add an alias to the count(), such as `SELECT COUNT(marvel_comic_character_name) as l_p`

Comment: this also doesn't work the error is still this same : SQL Error: 0, SQLState: 42703 
Unable to find column position by name: l_p [The column name l_p was not found in this ResultSet.] [n/a]; SQL [n/a]
the new sql query : `SELECT COUNT(marvel_comic_character_name)FROM marvel_super_heroes 
AS l_p WHERE marvel_comic_character_name ~* ':character'`

EDIT: after changing query to : `SELECT COUNT(marvel_comic_character_name) AS l_p 
FROM marvel_super_heroes 
WHERE marvel_comic_character_name ~* ':character'` i receive the same erro but for another column : `comic_appearance_1`

Comment: Isn't that to be expected? Why would comic_appearance_1 be in the results? The only columns that will be in your results are the ones that you have in the select part of your query. You only have one field in the select statement, so you will only have one field in the response.

Answer (score 0):

It looks like your SQL query `COUNT(marvel_comic_character_name)` returns just count, which is an integer.

However, you repository method returns `List<Character>`, which represents all columns from the table. And when driver tries to instantiate Character (which is, I assume, is the name of entity) - it starts from first column defined in entity - which is `l_p` - but it is not present in result set, which only has count returned.

For your repository to work - it looks like you need to change return type to `int`, so actual count would be returned